# Which is the correct word order: "Figure out how much are they willing" or "how much they are willing"?

Tags: word-order

What is the correct word order in this sentence?

> Figure out how much **are they** willing to pay.

Is it *are they* **or** *they are*? Also, what is the grammar rule for that?

Many thanks!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I don't know, but I rather doubt closed questions appear in the "related" suggestions. But there's no chance an automated routine would recognize the similarities between this Q and the one I linked to (this one's ***are they/they are***, that one's ***I should/should I***). But it's exactly the same issue, and this one's Off Topic for exactly the same reason as that one. And there was no need for anyone to provide an answer here, because it's exactly the same as the 4 answers on the earlier Q (subject/verb inversion applies to *questions*).

Comment: **Edited** Part 1. @FumbleFingers The idea of closing a question as a duplicate of a closed and off-topic question is not helpful to learners or to more competent speakers. I don't think closed questions pop up on the related questions list. Do they? **Part 2** The upvoted answer is not helpful–it's confusing (*…the question is expressed in the normal order*). Ack, I see this Q was posted in Apr 2018 and during this time has attracted a measly 85 views. While I agree it's a LQ question, it should be linked to an open question, which BTW, was posted in Dec 2019.

Comment: Please @FumbleFingers cast your vote to reopen the duplicate question which has attracted more answers and views.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You don't seem to have upvoted *any* answers on the linked question. Personally, I prefer the one from 'Anonymous' over BillJ's, so I've just upvoted it - but if you don't like either, perhaps you should post another answer yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No one can post an answer until it's reopened. That's my whole point.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression is "Figure out how much they are willing to pay".

When the object clause is a question, the question is expressed in the normal order.